# The session value stored into two columns instead of one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

I am facing a problem with below code. When I click on Repsendbtn it stores the same session value of `UsrNme` into both columns `Receiver` and `Sender`, where it is supposed to save session value into `Receiver` and into `Sender` the value of `tolbl`

```
<asp:FormView ID="repmsgform" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="mailno" Width="100%" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-lg-12"> 
            <form class="well span8">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="span3">
                      <label>From</label> 
                      <asp:Label ID="tolbl" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Bind("Receiver") %>'></asp:Label> 
                      <label>To</label>
                      <asp:Label ID="frmlbl" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Bind("sender") %>'></asp:Label>
                      <label>Ads Title</label>
                      <asp:Label ID="MsgTitLbl" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Bind("Mestitle") %>'></asp:Label>
                      <asp:Label ID="adsnummsglbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AdsID") %>' Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
                      <asp:Label ID="mailnolbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("mailno") %>' Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="span5">
                     <label>Message</label> 
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="150px" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                     </textarea>
                  </div>
                  <asp:Label ID="msgsentlbl" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="#669900"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Repsendbtn" Text="Send" CssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right" OnCommand=" Repsendbtn_Command"  CommandArgument='<%# Bind ("mailno") %>'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <asp:Button ID="Closebtn" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="btn btn-default pull-right" OnCommand=" Closebtn_Command" />
             </div>
          </form>
       </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Code:

```
protected void Repsendbtn_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
     if (Session["UsrNme"] != null)
     {
           using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc))
           {
                string SendMsgSQL = @"INSERT INTO mails (AdsID, Mestitle, Message, Receiver, sender, Date) VALUES (@AdsID, @Mestitle, @Message, @Receiver, @sender, @Date)";

                using (SqlCommand SendMsgcmd = new SqlCommand(SendMsgSQL, cn))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    var user = Session["UsrNme"];

                    SendMsgcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Receiver", user);
                    SendMsgcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", ((TextBox)repmsgform.FindControl("TextBox15")).Text);
                    SendMsgcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mestitle", ((Label)repmsgform.FindControl("MsgTitLbl")).Text);
                    SendMsgcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsID", ((Label)repmsgform.FindControl("adsnummsglbl")).Text);
                    SendMsgcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
                    SendMsgcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sender", ((Label)repmsgform.FindControl("tolbl")).Text);

                    SendMsgcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    viewmsgView.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Consider throwing an error (if these fields are required)
        }
    }
```

Comment: what values you are storing in session["UsrNme"] ? and where? provide that too

Comment: "UsrNme" it is the session value and this value is started when user login in and this value is Receiver

Comment: so which value you are not getting??

Comment: you have stored Receiver in session, so you are getting that, and you wan to get sender from "tolbl" . right??